# how link an outside page in my html page

Tags: html, css

I just want to link google page in my html code but nothing works. this is my  css  code.

```css
a:hover { text-decoration: underline }

.container, .main {
    width: 640px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    height: 300px;
}

.main { margin-top: 50px }

input {
    font-family: 'HelveticaNeue', 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 13px;
    color: #555860;
}

.search {
    position: relative;
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 300px;
}

.search input {
    height: 26px;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 0 12px 0 25px;
    background: white url("http://cssdeck.com/uploads/media/items/5/5JuDgOa.png") 8px 6px no-repeat;
    border-width: 1px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: #a8acbc #babdcc #c0c3d2;
    border-radius: 13px;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    -ms-box-sizing: border-box;
    -o-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px #e5e7ed, 0 1px 0 #fcfcfc;
    -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 1px #e5e7ed, 0 1px 0 #fcfcfc;
    -ms-box-shadow: inset 0 1px #e5e7ed, 0 1px 0 #fcfcfc;
    -o-box-shadow: inset 0 1px #e5e7ed, 0 1px 0 #fcfcfc;
    box-shadow: inset 0 1px #e5e7ed, 0 1px 0 #fcfcfc;
}

.search input:focus {
    outline: none;
    border-color: #66b1ee;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 2px rgba(85, 168, 236, 0.9);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 2px rgba(85, 168, 236, 0.9);
    -ms-box-shadow: 0 0 2px rgba(85, 168, 236, 0.9);
    -o-box-shadow: 0 0 2px rgba(85, 168, 236, 0.9);
    box-shadow: 0 0 2px rgba(85, 168, 236, 0.9);
}

.search input:focus + .results { display: block }

.search .results {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    top: 35px;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    z-index: 10;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    border-width: 1px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: #cbcfe2 #c8cee7 #c4c7d7;
    border-radius: 3px;
    background-color: #fdfdfd;
    background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%, #fdfdfd), color-stop(100%, #eceef4));
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #fdfdfd, #eceef4);
    background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #fdfdfd, #eceef4);
    background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #fdfdfd, #eceef4);
    background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #fdfdfd, #eceef4);
    background-image: linear-gradient(top, #fdfdfd, #eceef4);
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
    -ms-box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
    -o-box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
    box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}

.search .results li { display: block }

.search .results li:first-child { margin-top: -1px }

.search .results li:first-child:before, .search .results li:first-child:after {
    display: block;
    content: '';
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -5px;
    border: 5px outset transparent;
}

.search .results li:first-child:before {
    border-bottom: 5px solid #c4c7d7;
    top: -11px;
}

.search .results li:first-child:after {
    border-bottom: 5px solid #fdfdfd;
    top: -10px;
}

.search .results li:first-child:hover:before, .search .results li:first-child:hover:after { display: none }

.search .results li:last-child { margin-bottom: -1px }

.search .results a {
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    margin: 0 -1px;
    padding: 6px 40px 6px 10px;
    color: #808394;
    font-weight: 500;
    text-shadow: 0 1px #fff;
    border: 1px solid transparent;
    border-radius: 3px;
}

.search .results a span { font-weight: 200 }

.search .results a:before {
    content: '';
    width: 18px;
    height: 18px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    right: 10px;
    margin-top: -9px;
    background: url("http://cssdeck.com/uploads/media/items/7/7BNkBjd.png") 0 0 no-repeat;
}

.search .results a:hover {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #fff;
    text-shadow: 0 -1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
    border-color: #2380dd #2179d5 #1a60aa;
    background-color: #338cdf;
    background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%, #59aaf4), color-stop(100%, #338cdf));
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #59aaf4, #338cdf);
    background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #59aaf4, #338cdf);
    background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #59aaf4, #338cdf);
    background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #59aaf4, #338cdf);
    background-image: linear-gradient(top, #59aaf4, #338cdf);
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2), 0 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.08);
    -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2), 0 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.08);
    -ms-box-shadow: inset 0 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2), 0 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.08);
    -o-box-shadow: inset 0 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2), 0 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.08);
    box-shadow: inset 0 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2), 0 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.08);
}

:-moz-placeholder {
    color: #a7aabc;
    font-weight: 200;
}

::-webkit-input-placeholder {
    color: #a7aabc;
    font-weight: 200;
}

.lt-ie9 .search input { line-height: 26px }
```

```html
<section class="main">
  <form class="search" method="post" action="index.html" >
   <input type="text" name="q" placeholder="Search..." />
   <ul class="results" >
    <li><a href="http://www.google.com">Search Result #1<br /><span>Description...</span></a></li>
   </ul>
  </form>
</section>
```

i think `class="results"` in `ul` tag is the problem, because when i cut it , my link work but after my page don't have style

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Problem:**

Yes in fact, the problem is in the `search` class, besides that the link is working perfectly and redirect you to Google page.

**Explanation:**

You have `display:none;` in the `search` class style which is hiding it from the page. And if you remove `class="search"`, the `ul` will be shown but will loose all its style.

**Solution:**

To resolve the problem just remove the line:

```
display:none;
```

Or replace it with :

```
display:block;
```

**This is a working DEMO:**

```css
a:hover { text-decoration: underline }

.container, .main {
    width: 640px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    height: 300px;
}

.main { margin-top: 50px }

input {
    font-family: 'HelveticaNeue', 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 13px;
    color: #555860;
}

.search {
    position: relative;
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 300px;
}

.search input {
    height: 26px;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 0 12px 0 25px;
    background: white url("http://cssdeck.com/uploads/media/items/5/5JuDgOa.png") 8px 6px no-repeat;
    border-width: 1px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: #a8acbc #babdcc #c0c3d2;
    border-radius: 13px;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    -ms-box-sizing: border-box;
    -o-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px #e5e7ed, 0 1px 0 #fcfcfc;
    -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 1px #e5e7ed, 0 1px 0 #fcfcfc;
    -ms-box-shadow: inset 0 1px #e5e7ed, 0 1px 0 #fcfcfc;
    -o-box-shadow: inset 0 1px #e5e7ed, 0 1px 0 #fcfcfc;
    box-shadow: inset 0 1px #e5e7ed, 0 1px 0 #fcfcfc;
}

.search input:focus {
    outline: none;
    border-color: #66b1ee;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 2px rgba(85, 168, 236, 0.9);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 2px rgba(85, 168, 236, 0.9);
    -ms-box-shadow: 0 0 2px rgba(85, 168, 236, 0.9);
    -o-box-shadow: 0 0 2px rgba(85, 168, 236, 0.9);
    box-shadow: 0 0 2px rgba(85, 168, 236, 0.9);
}

.search input:focus + .results { display: block }

.search .results {
    position: absolute;
    top: 35px;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    z-index: 10;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    border-width: 1px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: #cbcfe2 #c8cee7 #c4c7d7;
    border-radius: 3px;
    background-color: #fdfdfd;
    background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%, #fdfdfd), color-stop(100%, #eceef4));
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #fdfdfd, #eceef4);
    background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #fdfdfd, #eceef4);
    background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #fdfdfd, #eceef4);
    background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #fdfdfd, #eceef4);
    background-image: linear-gradient(top, #fdfdfd, #eceef4);
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
    -ms-box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
    -o-box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
    box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}

.search .results li { display: block }

.search .results li:first-child { margin-top: -1px }

.search .results li:first-child:before, .search .results li:first-child:after {
    display: block;
    content: '';
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -5px;
    border: 5px outset transparent;
}

.search .results li:first-child:before {
    border-bottom: 5px solid #c4c7d7;
    top: -11px;
}

.search .results li:first-child:after {
    border-bottom: 5px solid #fdfdfd;
    top: -10px;
}

.search .results li:first-child:hover:before, .search .results li:first-child:hover:after { display: none }

.search .results li:last-child { margin-bottom: -1px }

.search .results a {
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    margin: 0 -1px;
    padding: 6px 40px 6px 10px;
    color: #808394;
    font-weight: 500;
    text-shadow: 0 1px #fff;
    border: 1px solid transparent;
    border-radius: 3px;
}

.search .results a span { font-weight: 200 }

.search .results a:before {
    content: '';
    width: 18px;
    height: 18px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    right: 10px;
    margin-top: -9px;
    background: url("http://cssdeck.com/uploads/media/items/7/7BNkBjd.png") 0 0 no-repeat;
}

.search .results a:hover {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #fff;
    text-shadow: 0 -1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
    border-color: #2380dd #2179d5 #1a60aa;
    background-color: #338cdf;
    background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%, #59aaf4), color-stop(100%, #338cdf));
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #59aaf4, #338cdf);
    background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #59aaf4, #338cdf);
    background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #59aaf4, #338cdf);
    background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #59aaf4, #338cdf);
    background-image: linear-gradient(top, #59aaf4, #338cdf);
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2), 0 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.08);
    -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2), 0 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.08);
    -ms-box-shadow: inset 0 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2), 0 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.08);
    -o-box-shadow: inset 0 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2), 0 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.08);
    box-shadow: inset 0 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2), 0 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.08);
}

:-moz-placeholder {
    color: #a7aabc;
    font-weight: 200;
}

::-webkit-input-placeholder {
    color: #a7aabc;
    font-weight: 200;
}

.lt-ie9 .search input { line-height: 26px }
```

```html
<section class="main">
  <form class="search" method="post" action="index.html" >
   <input type="text" name="q" placeholder="Search..." />
   <ul class="results" >
    <li><a href="http://www.google.com">Search Result #1<br /><span>Description...</span></a></li>
   </ul>
  </form>
</section>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have `display` set to `none` in 
`.search .results`.
Delete this statement: `display: none` or set `display` to `block`.

For more information please refer to [display property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/display).

Answer (score 0):

You're right that `.results` is the problem - `.search .results` has `display: none` which hides the entire block.

You'll need to remove this line for it to show.